# Pytorch's Autograd does not support complex matrix inversion, does anyone have a workaround?

Tags: python, pytorch, complex-numbers, matrix-inverse, autograd

Somewhere in my loss function, I invert a complex matrix of size 64*64. Although complex matrix inversion is supported for torch.tensor, the gradient cannot be computed in the training loop as I get this error:

RuntimeError: inverse does not support automatic differentiation for outputs with complex type.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue? a custom function instead of torch.inverse maybe?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the inverse yourself using the real-valued components of your complex matrix.

Some linear algebra first:

a complex matrix `C` can be written as a sum of two *real* matrices `A` and `B` (`j` is the sqrt of -1):

```
C = A + jB
```

Finding the inverse of `C` is basically finding two *real valued* matrices `x` and `y` such that

```
(A + jB)(x + jy) = I + j0
```

This boils down to solving the *real valued* system of equations:
[image]

Now that we know how to do reduce a complex matrix inversion to real-valued matrix inversion, we can use pytorch's [`solve`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.solve.html#torch.solve) to do the inverse for us.

```py
def complex_inverse(C):
  A = torch.real(C)
  B = torch.imag(C)
  # construct the left hand side of the system of equations
  # side note: from pytorch 1.7.1 you can use vstack and hstack instead of cat
  lhs = torch.cat([torch.cat([A, -B], dim=1), torch.cat([B, A], dim=1)], dim=0)
  # construct the rhs of the system of equations
  rhs = torch.cat([torch.eye(A.shape[0]).to(A), torch.zeros_like(A)],dim=0)

  # solve the system of equations
  raw, _ = torch.solve(rhs, lhs)
  # write the solution as a single complex matrix
  iC = raw[:C.shape[0], :] + 1j * raw[C.shape[0]:, :]
  return iC
```

You can verify the solution using numpy:

```py
# C is a complex torch tensor
iC = complex_inverse(C)

with torch.no_grad():  
  print(np.isclose(iC.cpu().numpy() @ C.cpu().numpy(), np.eye(C.shape[0])).all())
```

Note that by using inverse of block-matrices tricks you may reduce the computational cost of the `solve` operation.

Answer (score 0):

As of [1.9](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.9-released/), PyTorch now supports complex autograd.